# padding in printf (float)

Tags: c, windows, printf

I want to display in the title bar of an emulator the name, speed% and frame rate, something like

`<name> 100.00% 50.000fps`

The problem is, `speed` usually is either slightly below or above 100%, making it jumping left and right.

I know I can do padding "zeros"

`"%s at %05.2f%% speed, %05.3f fps"`

but a leading zero (like `099.89%`) looks really stupid.

Also, the default padding with spaces does not help, as obviously a space doesn't have the same witdh as a digit, so it jumps too.

Is this even possible (without using some fixed (monospace) font)?

Comment: Some proportional fonts (misguidedly) do not even make all the digits the same width, making it impossible to tabulate numbers properly.

Answer (score 3):

> *Is this even possible (without using some fixed (monospace) font)?*

Strictly speaking, no, it isn't. However, although the width difference between the space character and a digit is often quite considerable, the difference in width between digits is generally *much less*.

So, you can reduce the 'jumping' considerably by changing the number of decimal places (DPs), according to the magnitude of the value being displayed: 1 DP for "100.0", 2 DPs for (say) "42.42" and 3 DPs for values less than 10. Using the Stack Overflow (proportional) font, this looks like the following:

100.0
42.42
1.234

To achieve this in the `printf` function, you can use a fixed **width** specifier with a **precision** that depends on the base 10 logarithm of the value, passing the latter as a parameter to the `printf` format using the `*` specifier.

Here's a demonstration:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define max(a,b)  (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b))

int main()
{
    double a = 112.345;
    while (a > 0.0) {
        printf("%5.*lf\n", max(0, 3 - (int)log10(max(1.0, a))), a);
        a -= 12.345;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

112.3
100.0
87.66
75.31
62.97
50.62
38.28
25.93
13.59
1.240

---

As pointed out in the comments, the above solution will have problems in certain 'edge cases'; for example, when `a = 99.999`, the `log10` function will return a value around `1.9999996`, so the calculated number of DPs will be 2, but the output value will be rounded to `100`, thus displaying `100.00` instead of `100.0`.

A workaround for this is to provide a custom `ilog10` function, and use that to determine the number of DPs. For example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

static inline int ilog10(double x)
{
    int answer = 0;
    x += 0.5;
    while ((x /= 10) > 1.0 && answer < 3) ++answer;
    return answer;
}

int main()
{
    double a = 112.345;
    while (a > 0.0) {
        printf("%5.*lf\n", 3 - ilog10(a), a);
        a -= 12.345;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that, using this custom function, we can dispense with the need for the `<math.h>` header and the definition/use of the `max` macro.

Comment: Interesting idea to move the decimal point.  `(int)log10(max(1.0, a)))` has troubles when 1) `a` is just less than a power of 10 so the rounded output uses that wrong precision.  Try `a = 99.999;`  2) `a` is a power-of-10, yet `log10()` returns a value just under the expected integer value.

Comment: @chux Good points. Accuracy, precision and robustness are the keywords for answers on SO! Adding `0.5` to the returned `log10` value (before casting to `int`) resolves your first point, for sure (I tested `a = 99.999` before and after) ... I *think* it should also handle your second case (but I can't easily test that on my platform). Of course, there will be cases (such as `a >= 1000` and `a < 0`) that will fail - but that shouldn't be a problem in the OP's case.

Comment: @chux ... But that added `0.5` breaks lots of other cases! Working on it ...

Comment: @chux OK, Now I have a fix! The answer is turning into an essay, but there you go! :-)

Comment: FWIW, your idea is a good one, but pre-calculating the decimals needed is prone to failure in corner cases - you need to replicate what `printf()` is going to do.  Try `a = 99.9` with your latest - for me it made `" 99.9"`.  A better approach is to use `sprintf()` and post process the string.  Even that is tricky - I tried.  Problem is worthy of its own question.

Comment: @chux Yes - I can reproduce your `99.9` case. (Grrrr - corners, eh? Who needs them?) ... I'll need to apply a bit more brain-power to the `ilog10` function; I'm sure there's a way in that, *somewhere*.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Mole for your suggestion. I will check this out and see what it looks like. :)